# Expectation values of odd operators in case of even potentials are zero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, parity

Taking, for example, position operator (which is an odd operator), and then proceeding :

Assuming the eigenvalue of position operator $\hat x$ equal to $k$, can I not write:

$$\begin{align}
\langle\psi_n|x|\psi_m\rangle &= \langle x\psi_n|\psi_m\rangle \\
&=\langle k\psi_n|\psi_m\rangle \\
&=k\langle\psi_n|\psi_m\rangle \\
&=k\delta_{nm} 
\end{align}$$

But I know that $\langle x \rangle =0$ in case of even potentials (I don't know how that happens) and what I have written above is wrong, at least in case of even potentials.

Taking the example of infinite 1D square well, the states are :
$$ \psi_{n} \left(x\right)=A\sin\left(\frac{nx\pi}{L}\right)dx $$
then,
$$ \langle\psi_n|x|\psi_m\rangle =A\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin\left(\frac{mx\pi}{L}\right)x\sin\left(\frac{nx\pi}{L}\right)dx $$
If m=n=1,
$$ <x>=A\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\sin^{2}\left(\frac{x\pi}{L}\right)dx $$
if we apply an even potential then the equation gets reduced to$$ <x>=\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L}x\sin^{2}\left(\frac{x\pi}{L}\right)dx=0 $$ while in case of a potential(neither even nor odd), the equation leads to $$<x>=\frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}x\sin^{2}\left(\frac{x\pi}{L}\right)dx=L/2 $$ ?

Here $$ n=m=1 => $$ $$\delta_{nm}=1 $$ 
implying that $$ <x>=k $$ but $$ <x>=0 $$if$$V\left(x\right)=V\left(-x\right)$$ ,which is confusing me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expectation values of the position operator is equal to zero in case of even potentials?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/426037/)

Answer (score 0):

An eigenstate $\psi_n(x)$ of an even potential is going to have a definite parity of $\pm 1$, so of course $\langle n| x |b\rangle$ is going to zero. It has to be without doing the integral: there is no preferred side, so how can the system pick one? Odd eigenstates don't pick a side either, because the phase is arbitrary.

If you're shifting the origin of the system as to hide the symmetry, you're going to and answer that respects that symmetry, it's just not going to be $0$.

Why do you shift the support from $[-L/2,L/2]$ to $[0, L]$? Why not $[10^{100}L, (10^{100}+1)L]$? Would you not expect the position of the state to move with it?