# How to show that dipole moment of a system with definite parity is 0?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

By definition, $\hat q = q \hat r$ is the dipole moment. Given that the system has definite parity, show that the dipole moment is $0$ for a stationary state, that is, $\langle n |\hat q| n\rangle = 0$.

I wanted to try this problem in one dimension first, so what I did was:

$\hat q = q \hat x \implies\langle n |\hat q| n\rangle =  \langle n |q\hat x| n\rangle =q \langle n| \langle\hat x |n\rangle. $ and I was stuck here.

Definite parity given from the problem means the stationary states function must be either even or odd, is this something I can incorporate into solving this problem?

If I were to use this fact, then suppose $n$ is even, then $\langle\hat x| n\rangle$ is even$\implies\langle n |\hat x| n\rangle $ is even, and if $n$ is odd, still $\\\langle n |\hat x| n\rangle $ is even

Comment: You seem to have mixed up your $p$'s and $q$'s in a few places;  can you check them and edit to correct as necessary?

Comment: Thanks for the notice, I have edited it.

Comment: I don't know if this is very rigorous, but I guess one can calculate $\langle n|\hat{x}|n\rangle = \int \mathrm{d}x\, |\varphi_n(x)|^2 x$, where $\varphi_n(x) \equiv \langle x|\varphi\rangle$. Then you integrate over an odd function. For a finite intervall, i.e. from -a to a, this will vanish. However I am not sure if this is the case where you consider the whole real line. Edit: See also this post https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/426037/expectation-values-of-the-position-operator-is-equal-to-zero-in-case-of-even-pot and the answers therein

Comment: @Jakob your argument is exactly right.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I believe I can prove it in the 1-D case now. How would I extend it into the 3-D case?

Comment: @Rico, for 3d world logic is the same, try doing it component by component. e.g. can you prove that $\int dx \int dy \int dz \left|\phi\left(x,y,z\right)\right|^2\cdot x=0$ given that 
$\phi\left(x,y,z\right)=\pm \phi\left(-x,y,z\right)$ and same for $y,z$

Comment: @Cryo As we move into the three dimension doesn't the dipole operator change as well?  So shouldn't the integral not only have $x$ but something along the line of $\sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)$?

Comment: Dipole operator in 3d is $q\mathbf{r}$, where $\mathbf{r}$ is the position operator, which in position basis is simply position $\mathbf{r}=\left(x,\,y,\,z\right)^T$

Comment: Integral for 3d is over 3d space and has nothing to do with operator